# Laravel display validation errors and trim name

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to display errors to a user if validation fails, it sends a message back with status code 442 but I want to display error message inside a div. How can that be achieved? it doesn't neccessary have to be done with session('status').

ImageRequest

```
public function rules()
{   
return [
   'img' => 'file|image',
];   
}
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'img.image' => 'File type is not supported! Use files with extension .jpg/.jpeg/.gif',
    ];
}
```

Controller:

```
   public function testing(Requests\ImageRequest $request) {
        if($request->hasFile('img'));
        {
            $image = Input::file('img');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $path = public_path('images/' . $filename);
            Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(200, 200)->save($path);
            $file = $request->file('img');
            return ['url' => url('images/' . $filename)];
        }
           if($imgErrors = $errors->first('img'));
        {
           return redirect('template')->with('status', 'File type is not supported');
        }
        }
```

template.blade.php:

```
@if (session('status'))
<div id="mydiv" class="alert alert-success">
    {{ session('status') }}
</div>
```

JS:

```
function submitImage(){
    var fd = new FormData($("#upload_form")[0]);
        fd.append( 'img', $('#img') );

$.ajax({
      url:'template',
      data: fd,
      dataType:'json',
      async:false,
      type:'post',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function (data) {
        $("#image").attr("src", data.url);
                }
            });
        }
```

Another issue is that I am validating name of the website, and I only want to allow characters in alphabet and spaces, however if there is space I want to trim the words into one but it doesn't do it for some reason, and again display an error.

NameRequest

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'newName' => 'required|alpha',
    ];
}
```

Controller:

```
    public function postDB(Requests\NameRequest $request) {
    $newName = trim($request->input('newName'));
    $newLat = $request->input('newCode');
    $websites = new Website();
    $websites->name = $newName;
    $websites->html = $newLat;
    $websites->save();
    return redirect('template')->with('status', 'Website has been saved successfully!');
}
```

JS:

```
function updateDatabase()
{
    code2 = document.getElementById("content-link2").innerHTML;
    var name = document.getElementById("website_name").value;
    var newCode = document.getElementById('code').value = code2;
    var newName = document.getElementById('name').value = name;
    web_name = ($('#website_name').val());
        console.log(newName);
        console.log(newCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way i have found to return messages to the user is by using the `Flash` package built by Jeffrey Way

https://github.com/laracasts/flash

This can be used to return a message to the user with an error type.

---

For and example, In a controller you would do something like this

```
public function myFunction(Request $request)
{
    // Do your validation with the request

    if ($valid) {
        Flash::success('Congrats! Everything was fine');
    } else {
        Flash::error('Oops! Something went wrong');
    }

    return redirect()->back()->withInput();
}
```

---

It is possible to retain the content of one request and flash it to the view to repopulate the form. I would strongly recommend reading the Laravel documentation on this to gain a better understanding.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#old-input

Comment: ok so let's say I use this flash, how would I implement it so when function fails give an error? I don't want to redirect user, I want to keep the page as it is and if I do a return I will just get rid of the content user has created

Comment: @Przemek I have updated my answer with a basic example and a link to the Laravel documentation on retaining the content of older inputs. You should be able to implement a simple solution using a combination of the two.

Comment: } else { it's showing me unexpected '}' why? and you have if ($valid) what variable I need to use?

Comment: @Przemek I had missed a closing `;` by accident

Comment: if ($valid) what variable I need to use?

Comment: @Przemek use whatever variable you are using to track whether the request was valid. It you validation isn't a boolean you could even use a `switch` statement instead of an `if` to handle each type of response if you like. The implementation is entirely up to you!

Comment: and how would I display these messages in blade.php? and you have my code so you should be able to tell me :( I don't think I am using a variable

Comment: for example I already have 1 return therefore I cannot use another one